# Can I get pokégold without paying real money?

Tags: pokemon-go

So far the only option I found to get pokégold is by purchasing some for real money. But I've only been playing for half a day, so I'm hoping there might be other ways as well.

Particularly to get extra incubators. I mean, I collected 7 eggs today, average 5 km per egg. They can't expect me to walk 35 km each day?

Comment: We've been walking since 2012 November on Ingressland. Polish your shoes :)

Comment: For the eggs, each time one is done, you will get a new one. Don't expect you have to hatch them all everyday.

Comment: @ch7kor I'm currently equipped with 9 incubators, gotta hatch 'em all.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may get bonus gold from the Defender Bonus every 21 hours. To claim your bonus, tap the little shield on your Shop screen.

In order to be eligible for this, you must have Pokemon stationed on Gyms. Each Pokemon confers 10 Pokecoins / day, up to a limit of 100 / day.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that this is the only way to obtain it. Just to set it clear. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can get some coins without paying real money with your defenders bonus. You can get a daily bonus each day dependent on how many gyms you have a Pokemon on. During the beta, it was limited to 10 gyms for reward, but I've only had one day to test. I received 10 coins for having one gym this morning.

You can get this bonus by opening the shop and clicking on the shield in the top right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can take over a gym and you'll get gym rewards every day.

They contain pokégold in them.