# What can you get for free?

Tags: pokemon-go

Ive wasted my incenses by accident and have no way of getting pokemon money plus there are NO gyms or pokestops for miles. Is it at all possible to get either free money or incenses? If not is there anything I can get for free?

Comment: Where do you live?

Comment: Australia, on a farm, in what feels like the middle of nowhere

Comment: Let's try to get a good quality list of ways to ***earn*** pay to win items. A lot of users try to bypass microtransactions. This could potentially be a very helpful post

Comment: Related, if not an outright dupe of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272545/can-i-get-pok%C3%A9gold-without-paying-real-money/272603#272603

Comment: @Studoku The op clearly stated he has no Gyms nearby. So the answer on your link are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If google opinion rewards is available for you, you could use it to earn google credit for free, and hence potentially pokemon go items for free.

Otherwise, aside leveling up which give items too, I don't see a way.